# Django + ajax + modal form bootstrap5. How to make it work?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

No matter how much I did not try to fasten Ajax request. In case of success, a redirect should occur, in case of failure - an error output. All the ways that tried to implement already and I will not remember. I will be very grateful if somebody on this example will show how to work with Ajax. And where to register it correctly? In the basic template? Since if you specify  inside the modal template, it is performed too early before downloading the page.

View for authorization:

```
def login_view(request):
    """ Обработчик авторизаций, обращение происходит через ajax """

    # небольшая заглушка (Plug since one type of authorization is still disabled)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('type') == 'login':
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'login_type': 'login', 'msg': 'На данный момент данный метод авторизаций не доступен!'})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('type') == 'login':
            try:
                user: User = auth.authenticate(login=request.POST.get('login'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
            except Exception as error:
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'login_type': 'login', 'msg': str(error)})
            else:
                auth.login(request, user)
        elif request.POST.get('type') == 'token':
            try:
                user: User = auth.authenticate(token=request.POST.get('access_token'))
            except Exception as error:
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'login_type': 'token', 'msg': str(error)})
            else:
                auth.login(request, user)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'msg': 'Неизвестный тип авторизаций'})
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'msg': 'Запрос должен быть POST'})
```

Modal for authorization:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content rounded-5 shadow">
                <div class="modal-header p-5 pb-4 border-bottom-0">
                    <h2 class="fw-bold mb-0" id="loginModalLabel">Авторизация</h2>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body p-5 pt-0">
                    <nav class="mb-3">
                        <div class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                            <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-login-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                    data-bs-target="#nav-login" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-login"
                                    aria-selected="true">По логину и паролю
                            </button>
                            <button class="nav-link" id="nav-token-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                    data-bs-target="#nav-token" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-token"
                                    aria-selected="false">По токену
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-login-tab">
                            <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" disabled>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    На данный момент не работает, авторизация только по токену!
                                </div>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="login">
                                <p>Небезопасный, но удобный способ авторизаций. Двухфакторная авторизация не
                                    поддерживается! Лучше используйте авторизацию по токену.</p>
                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-4" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Логин от ВКонтакте" required>
                                    <label for="login">Логин от ВКонтакте</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control rounded-4" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль от ВКонтакте" required>
                                    <label for="password">Пароль от ВКонтакте</label>
                                </div>
                                <button class="w-100 mb-2 btn btn-lg rounded-4 btn-primary" id="logBtn" type="submit" disabled>Авторизация</button>
                                <small class="text-muted">Смена пароля отключит бота, нужно будет зайти на этот сайт, и авторизоваться ещё раз</small>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-token" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-token-tab">
                            <p>Токен можно получить на <a href="https://vkhost.github.io" target="_blank">vkhost.github.io</a> через приложение Kate Mobile.</p>
                            <form id="tokenForm" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="token">
                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-4" id="access_token" name="access_token" placeholder="Токен от ВКонтакте" required>
                                    <label for="access_token">Токен от ВКонтакте</label>
                                </div>
                                <button class="w-100 mb-2 btn btn-lg rounded-4 btn-primary" type="submit">Авторизация</button>
                                <small class="text-muted">Смена пароля или выход со всех устройств отключат бота, нужно
                                    будет зайти на этот сайт, и авторизоваться ещё раз!</small>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In the basic template connection [bootstrap.min.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) and at the very end [bootstrap.bundle.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the solution is not quite beautiful, but was able to implement using [jquery-3.5.1.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js) and [jquery.form.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.3.0/jquery.form.min.js) (v4.3.0). Here is an example, the code is in the basic template.

```
let tokenLoginForm = $('#tokenForm');
tokenLoginForm.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: tokenLoginForm.attr('method'),
        url: tokenLoginForm.attr('action'),
        data: tokenLoginForm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data['status'] === 'error') {
                alert(data['msg'])
            } else if (data['status'] === 'ok') {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert('Авторизация вернула неизвестный статус!')
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Не удалось выполнить запрос! ' + data)
        },
    });
});
```